# Algorithm to compare a list of word String to a list of regular expression

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, arraylist

I want to count the existence of words in textToBeTested array from expList.

Note that both expList and textToBeTested arrays can very large.

I can simply traverse both lists and use ".matches" method to count, but it is in O(n^2).

Is there any faster algorithm or implementation I can use?

```
    String[] expList = {"i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i'm", "bet[a-zA-Z]*", "my[a-zA-Z]*"};
    String[] textToBeTested = {"this", "is", "better", "than", "my", "method"};
```

e.g. in the above textToBeTested array, "better" and "my" matches with a string in expList arrays, so it will return 2.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about compiling all your patterns into a larger pattern that uses alternation? Alternation *can* be fast (like Aho Corasick or KMP) if it's compiled into a state machine correctly.

```
boolean first = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : expList) {
    sp.append("(?:").append(Pattern.quote(s)).append(')');
    if (!first) {
        sb.append('|');
    }
    first = false;
}

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sb.toString());

// Possibly make this a ForkJoinTask
int count = 0;
for (String s : textToBeTested) {
    if (pattern.matcher(s).matches()) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3286982 Yup. What you're basically asking for is Aho Corasick generalized to a regex. This is basically how you do that. Now, I'm curious how the performance compares.

Comment: The performance improved magically. Your method reduced the problem from O(n^2) to O(n) which contributes to the burst in performance. Thank you very much for the help.